# What is the most advanced video editing FLOSS?

Tags: software-rec, video-editing

There are so many video editors out there (at least half a dozen during my search), and I wonder which is the most advanced among them? How does it compare with commercial offerings?

Comment: I'm really not a fan of "most advanced" -- what specific things are you looking for?

Comment: @mic Nothing specific. I just want to know what is the GIMP of video-editing (i.e. the most highly regarded in its class).

Comment: **advanced** == **most complete** == **more features**

Comment: @Tshepang, == most reliable?

Comment: @kas Nope, doesn't count.

Comment: If "reliable" doesn't count in terms of "most advanced" for a linux video editor, then you clearly haven't used many linux video editors.

Comment: @steven Am lost in translation. Are you suggesting that the editors are unstable? If so, why do you think I'm suggesting that they are? My point was that the word advanced has nothing to do with stability. At least that's how interpret it.

Comment: My point is that almost none of the "popular" linux video editing suites are, in my experience, stable enough to count on.  It would be nice to have one that didn't choke on huge clip imports.  I would consider that an "advancement".

Comment: @steven Well, that would then be "what is the most stable/reliable ...". Anyways, I found `avidemux` pretty stable, but it often gives junk output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different ways of rating video edition software, and depending on which attribute (features ? user-friendliness?) you want to focus on, the answer to your question will be different.

Assuming you mean "Which Open Source video edition software is the most complete (it terms of features)", then the answer is probably [Cinelerra](http://cinelerra.org/).

To get an idea of how it compares to other video edition software, I suggest you have a look at the appropriate [Wikipedia page](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Comparison_of_video_editing_software).

Comment: Here is the wikipedia page I'm referring to [1], I just don't have enough reputation points yet to post more than one link in an answer

[1]https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Comparison_of_video_editing_software

Answer (score 3):

http://www.linuxalt.com/ shows Linux equivalents for Windows software; that might help

Answer (score 3):

[Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org)

I've only had a little experience with this, but I rarely need to edit video.  It crashed a few times when I used it about a year ago, but maybe it was just me or it's improved.  It's fairly easy to use as well.
The screenshots on the site show it in KDE, but I don't think it depends on KDE.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: So you do think this is the most advanced FLOSS in this category? Note that I'm not looking for a recommendation.

Comment: Then why the heck are you asking? To stay on topic Kdenlive is probably not as "advanced" as Cinelerra, whatever that means.